# What happens if humidity is 100%?

Tags: meteorology

What happens when the humidity is 100% in atmosphere. Does it heavily rains or fog formation occurs? Or is there any other possibilities?

Comment: If you don't feel the duplicate completely answers your question, edit your post to let us know what still needs answering and we can re-open the question for you.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Akhil, it is a really good Q. And a good answer already exists at http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/at-what-humidity-does-it-start-to-rain